# PHPUnit - how to test if a method properly creates a new item in the database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I want to write a function that creates a new item in my database, following TDD. I am using Laravel 9.x.

Running this test creates a new line in my database, I can see it by opening MySQL Workbench. But I want to use some assertion to test if it works without actually adding things to the database. The assertion below fails, and a new line is added to the database.

```php
public function test_it_creates_a_new_project ()
{
    $newProject = Project::create('Project 1');
    $this->assertNotNull($newProject);
}
```

Here is the `create` method:

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public static function create($name)
    {
        $newProject = new Project; 
        $newProject->name = $name;
        // $newProject->user_id = Auth::id();
        $newProject->user_id = 1; // Don't know how to fake a user ID in a test
        $newProject->save();
    }
}
```

What is the proper TDD way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to test that you can create a whole new project? I don't believe you would normally test that functionality. Even if you had a class that was instancing objects in the database, presumably Eloquent is doing the actual database inserts so you would just test that your class is calling Eloquent methods like `save()` correctly, and the actual database methods would be mocked in that test.

Comment: @leighboz you never mock a model in Laravel, never do that. Author, you can achieve waht you want, read this part of the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#assert-database-has. One more thing, please do not create `public static function create` as `create` exists, and is used by Eloquent, do not overwrite stuff